# Make a class template std::is_swappable

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to make a class template swappable. I don't understand why the static assertion fails:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct A {};

template <class T, class U>
constexpr void
swap (A <T>&, A <U>&) {}

static_assert (std::is_swappable_v <A <int>>);

int main (){}
```

It passes with

```
template <class T>
constexpr void
swap (A<T>&, A<T>&) {}
```

but shouldn't the first one also be OK?

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/vbWWxrec4

Comment: not sure, it might be a bug. What makes me suspicious is that with your original swap, msvc accepts `static_assert (std::is_swappable_with_v <A <int>,A<double>>);` but not gcc nor clang: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: it isnt a bug, but the discrepancy with `std::is_swappable_with_v` is a different issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::is_swappable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_swappable) (and `std::is_swappable_with`) considers `std::swap` too.

> ... are both well-formed in unevaluated context after using `std::swap`;

Then for the 1st case, the calling of `swap` is ambiguous between user-defined `swap` and [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). For the 2nd one, user-defined `swap` wins in overload resolution then `std::is_swappable` works as expected.