# Discrepancy with is_swappable_with_v

Tags: c++, swap, type-traits

This is a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68844718/4117728). A slightly modified version of the code, using `std::swappable_with_v` rather than `std::swappable_v` yields inconsistent results:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct A {};

template <class T, class U>
constexpr void
swap (A<T>&, A<U>&) {}


int main (){
    static_assert (std::is_swappable_with_v <A <int>,A<double>>);
    using std::swap;
    A<int> a;
    A<double> b;
    swap(a,b);
}
```

The static assert passes only with msvc https://godbolt.org/z/G6sj86sfq. Though all 3 major compilers accept the code when the static assert is removed: https://godbolt.org/z/hbdq4Eoh1

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_swappable) notes:

> This trait does not check anything outside the immediate context of the swap expressions: if the use of T or U would trigger template specializations, generation of implicitly-defined special member functions etc, and those have errors, the actual swap may not compile even if std::is_swappable_with<T,U>::value compiles and evaluates to true.

But the reverse should not happen, ie when a call to `swap` succeeds after `using std::swap` the trait should yield `true`.

Are gcc and clang wrong in rejecting the assert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gcc and clang are correct. From the behavior of [`std::is_swappable_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_swappable),

> If the expressions `swap(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<U>())` and `swap(std::declval<U>(), std::declval<T>())` are both well-formed in unevaluated context after `using std::swap`;

`std::declval<T>()` yields rvalue expression when `T` is a non-lvalue-reference type, it shouldn't be accepted by the user-defined `swap` (which accepts lvalue-references) and `std::swap`(which accepts only same types), the static assert should fail.

You should specify template arguments as lvalue-reference as:

```
static_assert (std::is_swappable_with_v <A <int>&,A<double>&>);
```

BTW: This is also how `std::is_swappable` does.

> provides a member constant value equal to `std::is_swappable_with<T&, T&>::value`

Comment: does this mean that msvc is wrong in accepting the assert?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, since `std::declval<T>()` yields rvalue expression when `T` is non-lvalue-reference type, it shouldn't be accepted by the user-defined `swap` and `std::swap`.